# These Directions Are Not Clear To Me

Tags: java, coin-flipping

I have to make a program that uses two files called coin. One file named coin and the other named coin tester. The directions in the book are confusing to me, but I still tried to do the assignment.

Here are the directions that were given:

> Create a Coin class that includes a variable faceUp that stores either a 0 for heads up or 1 for tails up, an accessor method named showFace() that returns a 0 if the coin is heads up or a 1 if the coin is tails up, and a
>   modifier method named flipCoin() that assigns a random integer between 0 and 1, inclusive, to the variablefaceUp.

Test the class with the following client code:

```
public class CoinTester{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coin nickel = new Coin();
        if (nickel.flipCoin() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Heads up!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails up!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the file named coin:

```
public class Coin {
    private int faceUp;

    public Coin() {
        faceUp = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    }

    public int showCoin() {
        return faceUp;
    }

    public void flipCoin() {
        faceUp = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    }
}
```

I know for sure I did it wrong because I'm confused and the program has syntax errors. I feel like it is not possible with the directions im given. The CoinTester is expecting a return method but I am not allowed to because of the directions.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Is the `CoinTester` code given as part of the assignment, or did you write that code?

Comment: *"but I am not allowed to because of the directions"* Where in the directions does it state that the `flipCoin()` method is not allowed to return a value?

Comment: @FredLarson That was given to me.

Comment: @Andreas is says a it has to return a modifier method which I thought that meant no return.

Comment: @LucasKopp Where does it say *"has to **return** a modifier method"*? I see *"Create a Coin class that includes [...] a modifier method named flipCoin() [...]"*. Doesn't say anything about whether that method has a return value.

Comment: @AndreasI looked up what a modifier method was and I still don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing the result of `flipCoin` to an integer.

but you defined flipCoin as `void` (no return).

one of these must change

As a side note:

There is no rule that says a modifier method is not allowed to return a value. While they typically don't, they sometimes  do return a value in order to save the programmer from writing an extra line.

Answer (score 1):

A method returns something if it gives information. flipCoin is not supposed to give information, but showCoin is. In fact, it's what you want to use in your if-statement to see what the state of the coin is. Furthermore, you'll want to flip the coin before viewing it. This code should work:

```
public class CoinTester{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coin nickel = new Coin();
        nickel.flipCoin();
        if (nickel.showCoin() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Heads up!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails up!");
        }
    }
}
```